# No data found/modified. using SAS/sql server libname and function delete

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I've tried to delete rows with month and year conditions in the ASO.TAB table knowing that the ASO lib is a SAS libname connected to sql server but I always receive No data found/modified. do you have a solution for this problem?

```
LIBNAME ASO sqlsvr schema="dbo" datasrc=Base 
user=XX pwd=XXX; run; 

%let Annee =%sysfunc(putn(%sysfunc(intnx(month, %sysfunc(today()), -1, same)),BEST.));
%let AA=%substr(%sysfunc(YEAR(&Annee)),3,2 );
%let MM=%sysfunc(putn(%sysfunc( month(&Annee)), z2.) );

proc sql;
  connect using ASO;
  execute by ASO
  (
   delete from TAB
   WHERE (MONTH(DAT_OPER)=&MM.-1 or MONTH(DAT_OPER)=&MM.-2)  AND 
   YEAR(DAT_OPER)=YEAR(&Annee.)
   ;
  );
quit;

NOTE: No data found/modified.
41         quit;
NOTE: PROCEDURE SQL a utilisé (Durée totale du traitement) :
      real time           54.84 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds
```

Comment: What will happen in January? Month is 1, so MM-1 is 0 and MM-2 is -1?

Comment: Before going to macros, do you have working non macro code?

Comment: You need to use SQL Server code in the explicit passthru.  Does it have MONTH() and YEAR() functions?  Also your logic will not remove any records that are for the previous YEAR.  So in January nothing will be removed since there are no month numbers of 0 and -1.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to write the appropriate SQL server code, then you can use SAS to generate that code.  Sometimes it's helpful to use SQL Server Management Studio or another SQL client to get the SQL Server code working.  Currently you are sending the following code to SQL server:

```
delete from TAB
WHERE (MONTH(DAT_OPER)=09-1 or MONTH(DAT_OPER)=09-2)  AND 
YEAR(DAT_OPER)=YEAR(23277)
;
```

Which looks like it has several potential problems.

Comment: how can i solve this problem? don't you have an example of SAS correction?

Answer (score 0):

The type of logic being used here is not correct, what happens in January, when M=1?

Assuming you want to delete the 2 and 3 months previous data you can do so with

```
proc sql;
delete * from aso.tab
where DAT_OPER between 
           intnx('month', today(), -3, 's')
           and intnx('month', today(), -2, 'e');
quit;
```

Comment: okey i will try to do this